# List calculations on powerquery power bi

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

How to make a calculations in Power Bi using whole list for all rows. I tried to do this way
[image]

but I got error "A cyclic reference was encountered during evaluation". Is this a way to put whole column in calculated fields and make with it some calculations?

This is my table [image]

My desire is for example if(OrderID{index}="A" then Shippedwwo{index} else Shippedowo{index -1} like in a picture below.

[image]

Comment: Show your sample data and your desired output from them.

Comment: You still don't show your desired output.  You will also need to show what you want for the first row, because, at the first row, `Index-1` is meaningless and will return an error.

Comment: I know for index -1 it will show error. I can deal with that. I edited post again to show my desired output without error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get your posted output, there is no need for the Index column (or for a custom function, for that matter).

```
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(previousStep, "test_column", 
        each if [Action]="A" then [Assignwwo] else null),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Added Custom",{"test_column"})
```

**orig data**
[image]

**output**
[image]